# Rainbow cracking attacks and Brute-force attack

Tags: security, cryptography

Hi a small question about Rainbow cracking attacks and Brute-force attack

does rainbow attack considerer as a variant of a Brute-force attack ?

**also in Brute-force attack it search for *all possible key values* and what does rainbow search ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brute force attack naively tries every possible value.

A Rainbow table is a method for compressing hashes as to reduce the amount of disk space needed to store series of hash-results. Very useful if you want to store lots-of-hashes to safe computation time. (A rainbow table attack is a specialisation of a precomputation attack.)

<s>You could build a rainbow table based on the results of a brute force attack, but you could also build one on the results of (for example) a dictionary attack.</s> *I learned that this statement is false.*

The nature of rainbow tables dictates that it is a brute-force attack. For a more complete explanation read: [Crunge](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/15/crunge)'s answer to [What are rainbow tables and how are they used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used/440#440)

Answer (score 2):

Jeff wrote a nice blog post on Rainbow cracking : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html . You may find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The rainbow search builds a table of all possible values and THEN attacks. Brute force build-attacks, build-attacks, build-attack (you get the idea)

Comment: everything is vulernable. nothing is exempt from brute force - you can only slow it down. the longer you key, the longer to break